# coverage.py not reporting error from run command

Tags: django, django-testing, coverage.py

I have a bash script that runs my tests:

```
#!/bin/bash
coverage run --source='directory_for_coverage' manage.py test
coverage report --fail-under=87
```

but when I run the script it only returns an error code if the coverage fails, not if one of the tests fails. I would think that because I am not using the `--ignore-errors` switch that `coverage run` should return the error code from the failing test. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a `set -e` command to my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
coverage run --source='directory_for_coverage' manage.py test
coverage report --fail-under=87
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you, it worked for me !**
The help set command give some details:

`-e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.`